# But how to use this to show that $ \ \int_5^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx \ $ is negligible as compared to $ \int_5^{\infty} e^{-5x} dx \ $?

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the integral $ \ \int_5^{\infty} e^{-5x}dx \ $ and use this to show that $ \ \int_5^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx \ $ is negligible.

**Answer:**

$ \ \int_5^{\infty} e^{-5x}dx =[\frac{e^{-5x}}{-5}]_5^{\infty}=\frac{e^{-25}}{5} $

But how to use this to show that $ \  \int_5^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx \ $ is negligible as compared to $ \int_5^{\infty} e^{-5x} dx \ $ ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\left[ \frac{e^{-5x}}{-5} \right]_\color{red}{5}^\infty$?

Comment: ok , that is good,

Comment: *Compared* to $\int_{5}^{+\infty}e^{-5x}\,dx$, the integral $\int_{5}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx$ **is not** negligible. Actually the title and the question body conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for $x>5$ we have $$ e^{-x^2} < e^{-5x}$$
 Thus $$ \int _5^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx \le \int_5^{\infty} e^{-5x} dx = \frac {e^{-25}}{5} \approx 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Let
$I(a)
=\int_a^{\infty} e^{-ax}dx
$
and
$J(a)
=\int_a^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx
$.

I will show that
$\dfrac12(1-\dfrac{1}{2a^2+1})
\lt \dfrac{J(a)}{I(a)}
\lt \dfrac12
$.

$I(a)
=\int_a^{\infty} e^{-ax}dx
=\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{-a}|_a^{\infty}
=\dfrac{e^{-a^2}}{a}
$.

Since
$(e^{-x^2})'
=-2xe^{-x^2}
$,
$-\dfrac1{2x}(e^{-x^2})'
=e^{-x^2}
$,
so
$(\dfrac1{2x}e^{-x^2})'
=\dfrac1{2x}(e^{-x^2})'-\dfrac1{2x^2}e^{-x^2}
=-e^{-x^2}-\dfrac1{2x^2}e^{-x^2}
$
so
$\int e^{-x^2}dx
=-\dfrac1{2x}e^{-x^2}-\int \dfrac1{2x^2}e^{-x^2}dx
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
J(a)
&=\int_a^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx\\
&=-\dfrac1{2x}e^{-x^2}|_a^{\infty}-\int_a^{\infty} \dfrac1{2x^2}e^{-x^2}dx\\
&=\dfrac1{2}I(a)-\int_a^{\infty} \dfrac1{2x^2}e^{-x^2}dx\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$J(a) < \frac12 I(a)
$
or
$\dfrac{J(a)}{I(a)}
\lt \dfrac12$.

Since
$\int_a^{\infty} \dfrac1{2x^2}e^{-x^2}dx
\lt \int_a^{\infty} \dfrac1{2a^2}e^{-x^2}dx
=\dfrac1{2a^2}\int_a^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx
=\dfrac1{2a^2}J(a)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
J(a)
&=\dfrac1{2}I(a)-\int_a^{\infty} \dfrac1{2x^2}e^{-x^2}dx\\
&\gt\dfrac1{2}I(a)-\dfrac1{2a^2}J(a)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\frac12 I(a)
\lt J(a)(1+\frac1{2a^2})  
= J(a)\dfrac{2a^2+1}{2a^2}
$
or
$\dfrac{J(a)}{I(a)}
\gt \dfrac12\dfrac{2a^2}{2a^2+1}
= \dfrac12(1-\dfrac{1}{2a^2+1})
$.

Answer (score 2):

By letting $I_1=\int_{5}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx$ and $I_2=\int_{5}^{+\infty}e^{-5x}\,dx$ we have

$$ e^{25} I_1 = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2-10x}\,dx,\qquad e^{25}I_2=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-5x}\,dx=\frac{1}{5} $$
and by just exploiting $e^{-x^2}\leq 1$ we get $e^{25}I_1\leq\frac{1}{10}$, such that $I_1\leq \frac{1}{2}I_2$.
On the other hand the ratio $\frac{I_1}{I_2}$ is not really negligible. We have

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-e^{-x^2})e^{-10 x}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2 e^{-10 x}\,dx=\frac{2}{1000}$$
hence
$$ \boxed{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{100}\leq\frac{I_1}{I_2}\leq \frac{1}{2}.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $0\leq e^{-x^2}<e^{-5x}$ for most positive $x$ values. You can use FTC to find $\int_5^{\infty} e^{-5x}dx$, but not the other integral.